# Execute tasks on the same thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have one async method that do multiple async tasks. And, I'm trying to call it more than once at the same time and each time it gets called and fails due to concurrency issue it recalls itself otherwise it finishes execution.

This task is also using a static variable and to be able to make this variable thread-safe since each of them has their own instance of this variable, I made it [ThreadStatic].

The following code will demonstrate what I mean: -

```cs
public class Program
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Account _account;

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Repeat(Func, 5).Select(func => Task.Factory.StartNew(func).Unwrap()).ToArray());
    }

    public static async Task Func()
    {
        try
        {
            // Doing multiple async tasks
        }
        catch
        {
            // If catches concurrency issue, try again
            await Func()
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if the task failed and recalled itself, it'd recall itself in another thread, hence doesn't have access to the same instance of the static variable.

So, how can I achieve this so that all recursive calls get the same value of the static variable ?

Comment: No, that's a wrong way to solve that issue. Why don't you pass this Account thing as a parameter to Func? And get rid of `ThreadStatic`. Btw, whenever you think you should use `ThreadStatic` think 3 or 4 times. Because most of the time it is a sign of bad design.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this isn't actually the case, I just addressed it like that so the readers can get what I'm trying to say quickly without bothering them with the full scenario.

Comment: Again: get rid of `ThreadStatic`, pass `Account` as a parameter. I can't imagine a scenario where it is worse than `ThreadStatic`.

Comment: Again: I'm not saying that it will fail, I'm saying that this isn't actually my code and this isn't actually the case.

Comment: If you have no control over the code, then what exactly you expect to happen? The code tries to access a changing variable between threads. That is broken beyond repair, unless you are willing to modify the execution runtime (i.e. the task scheduler). Which is a very bad idea, with unpredictable consequences. Fix the root cause, do not modify the engine to make it work.

Comment: In dotnet DI, I'm overriding a service with another service that uses a static variable for testing purposes. That's the static variable that I'm talking about. And, I'm trying to run more than one task at the same time that uses this service and they all use a different instance of the static variable.

Comment: I understand. If this service implementation is like you've shown us above, then it is broken. Either fix the implementation or use other code. And again: do not modify the car when a wheel is broken - just change the wheel.

Comment: The service actually implementation works using HttpContext, but for testing purposes, I'm overriding it values using this static variable that it reads from in the testing environment.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to get rid of the `ThreadStatic` variable completely. You may be able to replace it with an [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

If you *absolutely cannot* modify that code, then you can do a really dirty trick by temporarily seizing control of the thread pool threads and installing a single-threaded synchronization context on them, e.g., using `AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library:

```
public static void Main()
{
  Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Repeat(Func, 5),
     func => AsyncContext.Run(func));
}
```

But seriously, I wouldn't. Just change the `ThreadStatic` variable instead.